# Angular binding to an Object not ArrayList

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular and trying to loop through an object

**JSON**

```
employee {"fName":"mike","email":"XXXXXXXX@hotmail.com"}
```

**interface**

```
export interface Employee {
fName:string
email:string

}
```

**component**

```
    iEmployee: Employee[];
getITIMDATA() {
        this._ersaDet.getITIMData(this.ersaGlobalUID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.iEmployee = data;
            },
            error => 'GetAllCostCenetrs Method: ');

    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div *ngFor="let itim of iEmployee">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="Name" class="form-control" id="ntName" [(ngModel)]="itim.fName">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div>
```

the error I get when the code is excuted is

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code in subscribe is

```
data => {
    this.iEmployee = data;
}
```

what is the content of `data`? can you print the value of `this.iEmplyoee` after the assignment.

The TypeScript compiler is saying it is not an array of objects.

Can you create a simple working example? (on Stackblitz, plunkr, ....)

**UPDATE**

Seems you expect to receive a single record and not an array, so you can either:

- remove the `ngFor`
- change the code inside the subscribe to something like

  data => {
      this.iEmployee = [data];
  }

BTW, it's very weird you don't get error/warning from the compiler when you try to assign a single object to an Array of objects.
HAve you removed some chec in the `tsconfig` file?

Comment: when I do console.log(this.iEmployee) I get this [object Object]

Comment: try with `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.iEmployee))`

Comment: I Idid and got employee {"fName":"mike","email":"XXXXXXXX@hotmail.com"}

Comment: @MassimoCosta, OP doesn't get any warning because `data` in this context has a type of `any`, which can be assigned to anything, including an array, without error.

Comment: great it worked..my last question what is the magic of the brackets "[data]" ? just so I understand

Comment: well I'm making `this.iEmployee` an array of objects containing only a single record `data`.
BTW if you call alwayas returns a single record maybe you can use a scalar value and not an array.
If the answer works, do not forget to "accept" that

Answer (score 0):

You should return an array in json rather than a single object. Even if you have a single object you should return an array of single object.